# react native geolocation for android returning cached position

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

I was using Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service' library and the details are as follows. My mobile app is heavily depended on location (geo coordinates) hence getting the lat/lon correctly is a must. The problem I am facing is that android is returning the cached position. I have removed the maximumAge parameter in my code but still I am getting the cached lat long in android. Is there a way that I can always get the current location from the GPS in android in react native using this library? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
AndoidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


Location.js:
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

  getCoordinates = () => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        });
      },
      error => {
      }, { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000 },
    )
  };
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't provide any parameter then it will use the default value for that parameter. So, In this case, you removed `maximumAge` parameter, which default value is `INFINITY` as per [this doc](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service#getcurrentpositionsuccesscallback-errorcallback-options).

So, try passing `maximumAge: 0` in option and it will provide newly cordinates like this :

```
getCoordinates = () => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        });
      },
      error => {
      }, { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 0 },
    )
  };
```

Comment: I'll try this and give feedback, I was having the same issue