# I always get the default coordinates from "react-native-geolocation-service" library

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, google-maps, geolocation

I can't get the 'react-native-geolocation-service' library to work properly.

My problem is that from my position I always get the same coordinates:

Latitude: 37.4226711
Longitude: -122.0849872

Which are the google default coordinates when you can't find the location. (These latitude and longitude values correspond to Mountain View, California, the headquarters of Google).

(I use React Native CLI, not Expo)

In my "AndroidManifest.xml" I set the permissions correctly like this:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

And on the location of Android Studio I put a location chosen by me (for example in Italy)  and clicking on "SET LOCATION":

[image]

This is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import {check, PERMISSIONS, request} from 'react-native-permissions';

const LocationComponent = () => {
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null);
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(null);

  const CheckPermission = () => {
    check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
      .then(result => {
        if (result === 'granted') GetPosition();
        else {
          request(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            .then(newResult => {
              if (newResult === 'granted') GetPosition();
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    const GetPosition = () => {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        async position => {
          console.log('Coords', position.coords);

          const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;

          setLatitude(latitude);
          setLongitude(longitude);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.code, error.message);
        },
        {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000},
      );
    };
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Get Position" onPress={CheckPermission} />
      {location ? (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.locationText}>Latitude: {latitude}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.locationText}>Longitude: {longitude}</Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.locationText}>Getting location...</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  locationText: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

export default LocationComponent;
```

I just can't figure out why I always have the same Google default coordinates, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: same problem here. were you able to solve it?
Edit: the answer was the cache.. as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68464142/1199196